# How to select child with the same name as parent

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml

`<parent>
 <parent>
  <someChild></someChild>
 </parent>
</parent>`

I try to select the second parent with `//parent/parent` but with no luck I only get the first parent.

How do I select the second parent?

Comment: your xpath is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about a child element being named the same as a parent element.  For your XML, `/parent/parent` will select the second-level parent element (as will your `//parent/parent` XPath, although there's really no need to use the `descendant-or-self` axis).

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is correct if you want to select the more child element.

**Example XML**

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <parent>
      <someChild>1</someChild>
    </parent>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <parent>
      <someChild>2</someChild>
    </parent>
  </parent>
  <other>
    <parent>
      <parent>
        <someChild>3</someChild>
      </parent>
    </parent>
    <parent>
      <parent>
        <someChild>4</someChild>
      </parent>
    </parent>
  </other>
</root>
```

**Selected Elements with `//parent/parent`**

```
<parent>
  <someChild>1</someChild>
</parent>
<parent>
  <someChild>2</someChild>
</parent>
<parent>
  <someChild>3</someChild>
</parent>
<parent>
  <someChild>4</someChild>
</parent>
```

**Selected Elements with `//parent/parent/..`**

If you want both parents shown then use the above.

```
<parent>
  <parent>
    <someChild>1</someChild>
  </parent>
</parent>
<parent>
  <parent>
    <someChild>2</someChild>
  </parent>
</parent>
<parent>
  <parent>
    <someChild>3</someChild>
  </parent>
</parent>
<parent>
  <parent>
    <someChild>4</someChild>
  </parent>
</parent>
```